# Wax paper sticking to homemade taffy - what to use for wrapping?

Tags: candy

I am developing a recipe for a taffy, and the candy itself is turning out perfectly. The major problem that I'm encountering is that the wax paper squares I am using seem to stick to the taffy after about 2-3 days of being wrapped. This may be a function of humidity (we're in mid-atlantic states).

To make the squares I simply took storebought wax paper, cut into 4x4 squares, take 1" taffy pieces and twist the ends. Every recipe I have found has supported using this. For the first few days, this worked fine. However, soon after I noticed that the paper was starting to stick at spots. Now, on several of the taffies, you simply can't remove the paper, it has adhered completely to the candy.

I'm contemplating using edible rice paper, and then a wax paper around it, but I was hoping there may be some other suggestions such as rolling the taffy in powdered sugar, starch, or flour. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd give parchment paper a try. Either that, or give the candies a bit of time to dry before wrapping. (I'd post this as an answer, except both are wild guesses, since I've never made taffy...)

Comment: @Matthew what have you tried? what worked best?

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar issue with caramel coated nuts that I have been making. What I have found works well is to place the nut clusters in a large bowl (which has a lid) containing a mixture of powdered sugar and cinnamon, seal the bowl and shake 'vigorously', remove the remaining powder and shake again.

In your case you may not wish to use the cinnamon, and perhaps only cornstarch rather than powdered sugar. The powder coat will provide a non-stick barrier to your taffy, which should be only slightly sweet (powdered sugar) to neutral (cornstarch) and dissolve in the mouth very quickly. Depending on the flavor of your taffy you may find that adding a touch of cinnamon (or perhaps powdered ginger) might provide a bit of 'extra flavor'.

Comment: This is a good idea - in my case I may be able to use a mixture of superfine or powdered sugar and citric acid. I'll give it a shot!

Answer (score 1):

For a longer life, you can wrap your candies with cellophane or foil candy wrappers, which are somewhat tricky to google, but [available on the internet](http://www.candylandcrafts.com/twistingwaxpaper.htm).

Wax paper squares are also available, and are likely to be a higher grade than the consumer rolls available in the supermarket, but I have not tried these.

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried this, but it just might work. Have you tried giving the wax paper squares a very quick spray of nonstick spray? Perhaps even blot them with paper towels after spraying so that you can't even really tell that it's there.

Comment: I hope you try this and let us know if it works! :)

Comment: I will give it a shot and see if it helps! Stay tuned!

Comment: @Matthew Cool! I love experiments! :) I hope it works. Just a trick from ATK: To keep from making a mess with the spray, lay the paper on the inside door of your dishwasher to spray. (no mess)